# Parachain doesn't produce blocks, but worked with rococo-local

Tags: parachain

[Parachain url](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fws.parachain-collator-1.c1.sora2.soramitsu.co.jp#/explorer)
[Repository](https://github.com/sora-xor/sora2-parachain)

The parachain is based on polkadot-v0.9.13 that was the latest at the time of release.

The logs have neither warnings nor errors.

What can we do?

We have two collators and they have connection to each other and there is a connection to the relay chain.

There is no message "Starting collation".
The same configuration worked fine during testing with rococo-local.

Comment: Please provide more details. It is not clear what the problem is or the steps to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must upgrade. Breaking changes since 0.9.13 have landed, and no relay chain can support you presently. It may be easier to start over implementing your changes (adding pallets mostly I see) based on the version of the [parachain template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template) that **matches your target relaychain**.

Comment: How do I upgrade if it doesn't produce blocks? From this page https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/runtime-upgrades/ it looks like I have to actually submit some extrinsics. It wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: It seems paras.forceSetCurrentCode on a relaychain is the solution.